# Rotate Texture Based on Normal

Tags: node-editor, shaders

Currently, I'm seeking a technique to adjust the rotation of a wave texture connected to a normal input. However, my attempt to rotate it using a mapping node results in the wave texture merely shifting rather than actually rotating it.

Current outcome

[image]

[nodes] geometry(normal)  -->  mapping(vector)  -->  wave texture(vector)

Wanted outcome

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal near the top of the cylinder is the same as the normal near the bottom of the cylinder.  No use of raw normal coordinates is going to give us slanted lines-- given two identical inputs, you're going to get two identical outputs.

But other kinds of coordinates can differentiate between the top and bottom of the cylinder.  For instance, we could use generated coordinates to shear our normal coordinates:

[image]

Tweak the value in the math/multiply node to tweak the amount of shear.